# Not able to click link using chrome webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Webpage element]

Sorry for not crisp image (elements not aligned properly). The image shows the complete webpage where i want to click the link highlighted at the bottom of the image using selenium java chrome driver. I have tried using xpath and cssSelector, in both the cases i get element not found exception. Can someone please help on how can i click the desired element?

Comment: Can't you copy paste the DOM? If not, you know there is a `[PrtScrn]` button on your keyboard to take screenshots.

Comment: The webpage can only open on my work laptop. i do not want to use my work email to send pics/information to my personal email. Hence. i clicked images using my phone and then used my personal laptop to post the image and issue.

Comment: Just edit the post on your work laptop and post the actual text. It's pretty much unreadable at this point and you really aren't supposed to post text as images on SO. Please post the code that you have tried and any error messages.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I got my answer from Alex. For future posts, i will not post code as image. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code to find the element:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.switchToFrame("mainFrame")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xxxxxxx")
```

you should switch to the frame if the webelement is inside a frame, if there are many frames, you should switch to last frame which contain the webelement

Comment: Thanks Alex! This was helpful. i was not traversing to last frame before searching the element. I am able to make progress based on your suggestion.